# Roblox DDOS Server How to do?

Tags: testing, roblox, ddos, pen

In roblox somebody came up to me in a game and said they could ddos the server, I didn't believe them because tons of random kids say that they can "ddos" But then he said he would. To my amazement the server froze and all the people were stuck walking. I was just wondering If this was done with a free boot tool or something else? Because I would love to do that!

Comment: Vendv, be aware that DDoS attacks are a federal crime in the US punishable by prison time and a hefty fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

DDOS stands for Distributed Denial of Service attack. DDoS attacks are conducted by multiple sources that distrupts the traffic so that the service is unavailable. But there is probably protection that protects the servers against basic DDoS attacks. Probably what you have witnessed is just a kiddo who pretends to be "hacker".

Edit: Do not do any DDoS attacks by the way. Distrupting the traffic just so beacuse  you want the temporarily stop the access to the service is stupid and illegal.

Comment: for what it's worth, i don't think this question is worth answering and should probably be closed. once you get to 50 rep on your account you can post comments instead of answers. as it stands this answer prevents OP from deleting their question and could easily be found elsewhere on the internet. As happy as i am to see you helping, i'm going to give this a downvote because i don't believe it adds value to the stackexchange network, please don't take it personally :)

Comment: if i had enough rep i would just leave a short comment and leave. and you are right, i wasted my time writing this anwser but anyways...

Comment: You were helping someone out, that's never a waste of time. But "will this question help others out, not just OP" is a good question to ask before answering. I'm sure you'll have enough rep to post comments soon. Thanks for all you do